# Using rails3-jquery-autocomplete to avoid duplicate entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I'm using the rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem my artist field on a releases form and want to make sure any new releases use the id of an existing artist if found via autocomplete or create a new artist if not found. At the moment the autocomplete gem returns artists as expected but created a new entry even if that artist exists.

My models are as follows:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :releases
end

class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :artists
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }
end
```

And controllers:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @artists = Artist.find(:all, :order => :name, :group => :name)
end  

def create
    @release = Release.find(params[:release_id])
    @artist = @release.artists.create(params[:artist])
    redirect_to release_path(@release)
end

def destroy
  @release = Release.find(params[:release_id])
  @artist = @release.artists.find(params[:id])
  @artist.destroy
  redirect_to release_path(@release)
end
end

class ReleasesController < ApplicationController
 autocomplete :artist, :name

def new
  @release = Release.new
  @release.artists.build
end

def create
  @release = Release.new(params[:release])
  @release.user_id = current_user.id
end
end
```

My routes contains:

```
resources :releases do
  get :autocomplete_artist_name, :on => :collection
end
```

And finally the artist fields:

```
<%= f.fields_for :artists do |builder| %>
 <%= render 'artist_fields', :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

(The rendered fields)

```
<%= f.label :name, "Artist" %><br />
<%= f.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_artist_name_releases_path, :class => "text" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you watch this railscast on [autcomplete associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association?autoplay=true)

It clearly does what you need.
I don't want to spoil your viewing pleasure, but it all revolves around `find_or_create_by`

Comment: I did watch and follow that but couldn't get it working.....i'll give it another go.

Comment: It is saving it as nested - where would one put "find_or_create"?  Do we need to "un-nest" it, then save the nested-object separately?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you fetch the id of the artist with
    :id_element => '#artist_id' on the f.autocomplete_field?
If the artist_id param does not come back, you can create it